# DataTables Processing Message Stuck on Grid Reload

Tags: jquery, datatables

I've "successfully" implemented DataTables into my app. The grid loads completely fine initially from the server with no problems. However, when I call the `ajax.reload();` method on my grid, the `Processing` message is stuck there, almost as if the JSON is bad or the call to the server failed.

I checked the JSON both on the initial call and after the `ajax.reload()` call and it's *exactly* the same both times - no JSON errors at all, the exact same JSON string.

Why on the subsequent call to the server, even with the same exact JSON returned both times, does the `Processing` message stick?

Here's my code:

```
var objUserTotalsTable = $('#tbl-qmes-tasking-user-totals').DataTable({
        processing: true,
        language: {
            processing: '<span class="fa fa-refresh fa-spin fa-3x fa-fw datatable-spinner"></span><div class="loading-text">Loading</div>'
        },
        info: false,
        serverSide: true,
        ordering: false,
        paging: false,
        searching: false,
        ajax: {
            url: "Models/crud/Reports/qmes-tasking-select.aspx",
            data: {
                valSwitch: "user_totals"
            },
        }
    });
```

Comment: Which DataTables version are you using? **oLanguage** is legacy code. The new **language.processing** option is [like this](https://datatables.net/reference/option/language.processing).

Comment: @EmreBolat I'm using 1.10.12... I just tried changing my code to use the new `language.processing` (see updated code above) but the `Processing` message still stays there on any subsequent grid load. Very strange. Both the initial call (which works perfectly) and any subsequent calls (which makes the `Processing` message stick) are returning the exact same JSON string with no errors.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You have server-side processing enabled with `serverSide: true`. In that mode server should return `draw` parameter in the response containing the same value as in the request. The value starts at `1` and increments with every request.

Most likely you're returning the same value in `draw` parameter and that's why your subsequent responses are ignored.

See [server-side processing documentation](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side) for more details.

Comment: You're a life-saver!

Comment: This helped me as well. Since i was caching in Redis and forgot to change the draw parameter before returning response when returning from cache instead of DB.

Comment: This helped, as I was not checking the "draw" value, but the issue remained. Do you have any other idea about what may be causing this?  Thank you!